# Google DevTool Timeline: Forced reflow is likely performance bottleneck

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I added parallax effect to my page. And now I have problems with performance and FPS and many questions :-)

I use `transform3d` and `requestAnimationFrame` to realize it (like this recomended http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/).

My code looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  latestKnownScrollY = window.scrollY;
});

function updateParallax() {
  var y = latestKnownScrollY * 0.4;
  element.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, ' + y + 'px, 0)';
  requestAnimationFrame(updateParallax);
}

updateParallax();
```

Sometimes I have warnings like on the screenshot:

> Forced reflow is likely performance bottleneck

[image]

Call stack points to `latestKnownScrollY = window.scrollY`.

But why this warning appears only occasionally? I use `window.scrollY` each scroll event.

Comment: Could you post a demo somewhere (e.g. on CodePen)? Spend an hour trying to replicate it but haven't been able to so far.

Comment: The code you have provided so far doesn't appear to cause any bottlenecks, but combined with other code omitted there could well be some performance issues detected based on the number of DOM elements on the page that are involved in the recalculation. Some useful information can be found [Avoid large complex layouts and layout thrashing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing) and [What forces layout / reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)

Comment: I tested again. And I noticed a pattern: this warning appears when I scroll page and  cursor on button with CSS transition (background color only).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each time you read `window.scrollY`, you're causing a reflow. It just means that the browser is calculating the styles and layout to give you the value.

It says it's *likely* a performance issue because it takes time and it is synchronous. If you read, set, read, set, read, set properties, or if you have this kind of thing inside a loop, it will cause a bottleneck until it can redraw the whole page all the times you triggered the reflow. The solution is usually first to read everything you need, then set everything you need to change.

But in your case, it shouldn't be a problem. It says it takes just 0.2 ms and it's doing it just once. Do you notice any performance issue? Like a lag when you scroll?

Comment: Yes, I have lags when scrolling on slower computers.

Comment: As I mentioned above I noticed scrolling lags when css animation (for example hover animation of background color, opacity or transform) works. This warning appears as result.

Comment: Honestly I think that's just lack of resources in the slower machine. Animations are expensive.

Comment: I am using `window.requestAnimationFrame` with scroll function in the callback to prevent the violation